# AFNetworking JSON request to WCF REST service

Tags: objective-c, ios, wcf, rest, afnetworking

I'm using AFNetworking for my REST service (WCF). Here is code:

```
  NSDictionary *userName = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"user" forKey:@"UserNameOrEmail"];
  NSDictionary *pass = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"123" forKey:@"Password"];
  NSArray *credentials = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:userName,pass,nil];
  NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:credentials forKey:@"request"];


  AFHTTPClient *client = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:
  [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://server"]];

  [client postPath:@"/ProfileWebService.svc/login" parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSString *text = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Response: %@", text);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
}];
```

but I get 400 HTTP Error.

Using HTML and AJAX it looks like:

```
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#login_call").click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'http://server/ProfileWebService.svc/login',
                    contentType : 'application/json',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: JSON.stringify({request: {UserNameOrEmail: $('#login_username').val(), Password: $('#login_password').val()}}),
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('#login_result').val('Code: ' + data.LoginResult.Code + '\nFault String: ' + data.LoginResult.FaultString);
                    }
                });
            });

        });
```

and works fine.

What's wrong with parameters.

Comment: More detailed AFNetworking docs studying gave me an answer, I should to add only one row of code

      client.parameterEncoding = AFJSONParameterEncoding;
That's it!

Comment: Can you post your comment as an answer and accept it?

Comment: I have no enough karma, only in 6 hours after I asked the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More detailed AFNetworking docs studying and search on the Stackoverflow gave me a **SOLUTION**:

1.Parameters for request should be like this:

```
  NSDictionary *params =
        [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
           [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                           username.text, @"UserNameOrEmail",
                           password.text, @"Password",
                           nil],
        @"request",
        nil];
```

2.Creating AFHTTPClient

```
  AFHTTPClient *client = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:
        [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://server"]];
```

3.As I send JSON as parameters I have to add:

```
  client.parameterEncoding = AFJSONParameterEncoding;
```

After I did this I got rid of 404 error,but I couldn't make anything with JSON response, I don't know why. But the solution is:

4.Creating a request:

```
  NSMutableURLRequest *request = 
  [client requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"/ProfileWebService.svc/login" parameters:params];
```

5.Creating an operation:

```
  AFJSONRequestOperation *operation =
  [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request
  success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON)
  {
     NSLog(@"JSON: %@", [JSON valueForKeyPath:@"LoginResult"]);
     NSLog(@"Code: %@", [[[JSON valueForKeyPath:@"LoginResult"] valueForKeyPath:@"Code"] stringValue]);
     NSLog(@"FaultString: %@", [[JSON valueForKeyPath:@"LoginResult"] valueForKeyPath:@"FaultString"]);
  }
  failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON)
  {
     NSLog(@"error opening connection");
  }];
```

6. Start the operation:

```
  [operation start];
```

Hope some AFNetworking beginners find this post helpful.